# Process sequence of elements in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, loops, sorting, tuples

Given a sorted sequence of pair, I combine the elements if they are continuous or smaller and skip if they are not.
For example:
if A = Seq((1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(8,10)(11,15))

output should be Seq((1,6),(8,15))

since last element of current entry is continuous with first element of next entry

if B = Seq((1,4),(3,5),(6,7),(9,10)(11,15))

output should be Seq((1,7),(9,15))

since last element of current entry is smaller with first element of next entry

I tried something like:

```
val finalOut = mySeq.sliding(2).map {
          case Array(x, y, _*) => (x, y, (x._2 - y._1))
        }.toList
```

The problem with this is it will just take 2 elements at a time, whereas we need to keep traversing unless there is a gap in continuity. I am not sure how to obtain that in scala.

I tried implementing for loop as well, but that also doesn't help, because it processes one element at a time and doesn't help in keeping a track of other elements or counter like c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `foldRight` and accumulate into a new `Seq`.

This works

```
val tups1 = Seq((1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(8,10),(11,15))
val tups2 = Seq((1,4),(3,5),(6,7),(9,10),(11,15))


def f(tups: Seq[(Int, Int)]): Seq[(Int, Int)] = {

  val emptySeq: Seq[(Int, Int)] = Seq()

  tups.foldRight(emptySeq){ (next, accum) => accum match {
    case Nil => Seq(next)
    case (a, b) +: cs if a - 1 <= next._2 => (next._1, next._2 max b) +: cs
    case _ => next +: accum 
  }}
}

f(tups1) // Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((1,6), (8,15))
f(tups2) // Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((1,7), (9,15))
```

I'd use foldRight over foldLeft because Seq's are Lists under the hood, and for Lists, prepend is constant, while append is O(n), and foldRight lets you accomplish this with only prepends.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Comment: Nice solution.  In the 2nd case, as `next._2` could be larger than `b` it should probably return something like `(next._1, next._2 max b) +: cs` to cover cases like `Seq((1,7), (3,6), (9,10))`.

Comment: @Shrey it's pattern matching on `accum`, which is the `Seq[(Int, Int)]` you're accumulating as your result. `(a, b)` is the head, `cs` is the tail. `next` is the next tuple in the input `tups`, which you're iterating right-to-left (via `foldRight`).

Comment: @LeoC good point. editing answer to incorporate.

Comment: `Seqs` are not `Lists` they may be, they may not. If you want a `List` use a `List` rather than the _(useless IMHO)_ interface. - Also, you may use `Seq.empty[T]` instead.